# How can I tell if I remembered to provide my SEVIS for my DS-160?

Tags: visas, usa

I have completed the Online Nonimmigrant Visa Application (DS-160) as an F1 student. However, the personal copy I received after completing the application does not indicate that I ever provided a SEVIS number, and I cannot remember if I did. The confirmation page has as far as I can tell no information of the SEVIS either.

How can I tell if I remembered to provide my SEVIS number for my DS-160?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve your application via the State Department's [Consular Elecronic Application Center](https://ceac.state.gov/GENNIV/Help/Content/Retrieve%20an%20Application%20ID.htm).

Comment: I tried this, but it was not helpful.

Comment: Since you need the DS-160 bar code number, SEVIS number, MRV receipt and your passport number to make your appointment, you can correct the oversight in person at the time of your interview.